# Should I cancel two weeks notice and balance two jobs?

Tags: negotiation

Edit: Further context was requested to be provided. So original post has been re written for clarity.

I was offered a new job, the start date is the 17th of April. I contacted the manager on what specific date the company will open, but he has said such a date has not been set yet, but the business is aiming to be ready  in the summer. So in the meantime the company will have me do training and preparation until the business is ready for operation. I am still working at my current job. However, I recently put in a resignation letter that is effective on the 17th of April due to the prospect of the new employer.

If the training and preparation does not offer that many hours, should I cancel my letter of resignation and balance the two jobs until the new company starts operation? And is it even possible to cancel the resignation notice once it is requested?

Answer (score 4):

First, get a solid start date from your new employer. Both when you will start needing to show up and when you will start getting paid. Once you know that, if you want to work at your old employer past Apr 17th, you can ask your manager if that's possible. It will be company-specific as to whether you can or not. But you can't go and discuss this until you know all the specifics of the new job.

Answer (score 2):

> If the training and preparation does not offer that many hours, should I cancel my letter of resignation and balance the two jobs until the new company starts operation?

If the new company is paying you from 17th April, then I think you should just commit to that date and company full time and focus on whatever they need you to train yourself and prepare. If this is not occupying your full day, this could also be any opportunity to go an extra mile and do some learning/training/ on your own which can help you prepare for next job. There is a chance the new company will positively look at your commitment and help in your career growth.

I just think trying to balance two corporate jobs will not do justice to either of them. Of course every situation is different, so you would have to take that call if you are able to do each job without conflicting on commitment to other.

> And is it even possible to cancel the resignation notice once it is requested?

This just depends on the company and how valuable you are. My current job actually reduced my notice period and I could not do anything about it but my last job where I stayed for six years asked me to reconsider my move and take back my resignation till my very last day in the company!